# Django app on Google App Engine Standard slows down after 15 requests

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I deployed a Django app on Google App Engine Standard with a F4 machine. The API is doing some machine learning and the processing has a duration of around 4s in local (between 3.5 and 4s). For my use case, it would be ok to have also 4-5s delays with the deployed app. However, when I test the deployed app doing the same request multiple times, I saw that the first requests take 3-4 seconds, but after 10-15 iterations, they take around 8s.

Here is the code I used to test my app:

```
session = requests.Session()

all_times = []
for i in range(50):
    try:
        t0 = time.time()
        resp = session.post(url_api, headers=headers, json=data)
        t1 = time.time()
        print(t1 - t0)
        all_times.append(t1 - t0)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Err", e)
```

The results of the request durations are as follows:

[image]

I wonder why there is this gap after 15 requests and why some points are way above the average 7-8s (e.g. 10s).

I get the same pattern looking at the latency in the Google Cloud Console:

[image]

#### What I tried

I tried to change the autoscaling parameters, thinking that it could be because of the creation of instances. But I got the same pattern when I restrict the number of instance to 1 with this in `app.yaml`:

```
automatic_scaling:
  max_instances: 1
```

I also tried to:

- Use session in `requests` to avoid creating a new session at each iteration.
- Do my requests using curl, which leads to the same results.

My goal is to minimize the variability and keep the request durations below 5s.

#### Update

Here is an example of the trace list from Cloud Trace, which shows the same pattern:

[image]

[image]

I compared traces associated with a large latency and traces with a lower latency, but didn't find any important difference.

#### Update 2

Thanks to the answer of Priyashree, setting the `min_idle_instances` to 1 to avoid machine restart solved the problem:

[image]

Comment: Check the logs to see what is going on.  You could be running out of memory and starting new instances.

Comment: @gaefan Thanks for your comment, but as explained, I fixed the number of instance to 1 to be sure that it would not be the origin of the problem.

Comment: If your one instance runs out of memory then it will crash and GAE will create a new one.  That process is slow.

Comment: I see! However, I make the requests one by one, so how could the instance run out of memory?

Comment: Hi @hhh I have few questions for you. 1. Are you deploying a Django app in GAE Standard with F4 instances( autoscaling) and making requests to your API which runs machine learning on it? If yes, where is your API served App Engine Flex/ App Engine Standard? 2. Also, can you use [Cloud Trace](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/management-tools/want-to-know-why-your-application-is-slow-cloud-traces-new-features-can-help) and analyse the requests and come back to me with the logs?

Comment: Hi @PriyashreeBhadra, thanks for your comment. It is App Engine Standard. I updated the post with some info from Cloud Trace.

Comment: Show me the Trace logs, I think this is a report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When comparing Google Cloud Platform performance with the local one you should keep in mind that deploying on GCP needs more time to import all the necessary libraries and set up the Django framework.

In general it doesn't make much sense to compare the performance on your local machine with the performance on GCE, as local machines are likely running a different OS. But yes, I agree the difference in latency between the requests served by GAE after 10-15 requests is not acceptable and quite strange.

Check the following :

- If the instance has exceeded the maximum memory for its configured
  [instance_class](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#instance_class) which is F4 in your case which may cause shut down of
  your instance and App Engine creating a new one in its place as this
  could be due to not having any available instances since that's about
  the time it takes for an instance to be deployed and you have set
  max_instances to 1.
- If you have set any [target_cpu_utilization](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref#scaling_elements). It specifies the CPU
  usage threshold at which new instances will be started to handle
  traffic when old instances reach the target CPU usage.
- The interval at which you are sending requests matters as you
  mentioned in your comments, “you are making the requests one by one”.
  When request volumes decrease, App Engine reduces the number of
  instances. When an application is not being used at all, App Engine
  turns off its associated dynamic instances, but readily reloads them
  as soon as they are needed. Reloading instances can result in
  additional latency for users. To make sure, you are not reloading
  instances, specify a [minimum number of idle instances](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#min_idle_instances). Setting an
  appropriate number of idle instances for your application based on
  request volume allows your application to serve every request with
  little latency, unless you are experiencing abnormally high request
  volume.

Also, as per [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#instance_class) if instance_class is set to F2 or higher, you can optimize your instances by setting [max_concurrent_requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#max_concurrent_requests) to a value higher than the default value of 10. To determine the optimal value, gradually increase it and monitor the performance of your application.

Go through [PageSpeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) Insights, which analyzes the content of a web page, then generates suggestions to make that page faster and could be handy. I would also suggest you to contact Google Support for a 1:1 interaction as this case/issue is environment specific.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that setting min_idle_instances can improve the problem (see my update). Still some points with high latency, any idea why? Is it possible to have more memory than F4 machines? With `min_idle_instances=1`, is the machine always turned on, and so larger costs?

Comment: Yes, assuming you are using first generation F4 instance class, you probably have 512MB. Using F4_1G gives you 1024 MB. If you are using second generation instances, you will have double the memory. F4 becomes 1024 MB, F4_1G becomes 2048 MB. Details in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard#instance_classes). Yes on setting `min_idle_instances=1` you are charged for the number of instances specified, whether or not they are handling requests but the advantage as I mentioned is the pending latency will have less effect on your application's performance.

Comment: You can go through this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/troubleshooter/latency) to see if you can improve your app's performance from the metrics mentioned here.